# Django does not gracefully close MySQL connection upon shutdown when run through uWSGI

Tags: mysql, django, uwsgi

I have a Django 2.2.6 running under uWSGI 2.0.18, with 6 pre-forking worker processes. Each of these has their own MySQL connection socket (600 second CONN_MAX_AGE). Everything works fine but when a worker process is recycled or shutdown, the uwsgi log ironically says:

**Gracefully killing worker 6 (pid: 101)...**

But MySQL says:

**2020-10-22T10:15:35.923061Z 8 [Note] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'xxxx' user: 'xxxx' host: '172.22.0.5' (Got an error reading communication packets)**

It doesn't hurt anything but the MySQL error log gets spammed full of these as I let uWSGI recycle the workers every 10 minutes and I have multiple servers.

It would be good if Django could catch the uWSGI worker process "graceful shutdown" and close the mysql socket before dying. Maybe it does and I'm configuring this setup wrong. Maybe it can't. I'll dig in myself but thought I'd ask as well..

Comment: Honestly, if this "notice" is nothing to worry about, you should fix this at the logging component and set [`log_error_verbosity`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity) to 2.

Comment: @Melvyn You could, but you definitely should not.

Comment: I don't see the virtue of logging what you ignore. If it hides other messages that might be useful, I suggest logging to a named pipe with a grep or a syslog that can filter out specific messages.

Comment: Yes, but I don't ignore it, that is why I posted this question :) Actually I think it can be bad, as it might point to misconfigurations that maybe kill ongoing requests during a rolling upgrade and stuff like that. For example I have a load balancer and Docker containers with nginx, uwsgi and Django inside, and I want to gracefully upgrade the containers. This question is not about that, but I have seen this flow leave requests hanging and fixing all errors related to shutdowns seems proper.

Comment: I don't think Django gets informed of an impeding interpreter reload. At least I can't find any evidence of it. Ok, `max_age = self.settings_dict['CONN_MAX_AGE']`.

Answer (score 1):

If CONN_MAX_AGE is set to a positive value, then persistent connections are created by Django, that get cleaned up upon request start and request end. Clean up here, means if they are invalid, had too many errors or have been started longer than CONN_MAX_AGE seconds ago.

Otherwise, connections are closed at request close. So this problem occurs when you are using persistent connections and do uWSGI periodic reloads, by design.

<s>There is [this bit of code](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/uwsgi.c#L1311), that calls instructs uwsgi to shutdown all sockets, but I'm unsure if this is communicated to Django or that uwsgi uses a more brutal method and is causing the aborts.</s> That shuts down all uwsgi owned sockets, so from the looks of it, unix sockets and connections with webserver. There's no hook either to be called just before or during reload.

Perhaps this get you on your way. :)